# Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property when submitting react form

Tags: django, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I was following a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@viewflow/full-stack-django-quick-start-with-jwt-auth-and-react-redux-part-ii-be9cf6942957) on how to link react with redux to a django api.  I have the django API set up and confirmed working.  But trying to connect react to it I've run into an issue I cannot solve.

Note:  The code from the tutorial can be viewed [on github](https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/master/_articles/redux_jwt_auth/frontend/src).  I think the issue in in the [`Login.js`](https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/blob/master/_articles/redux_jwt_auth/frontend/src/containers/Login.js) file, the code of which is below:

```
const Login = (props) => {
    if (props.isAuthenticated) {
        return (
            <Redirect to='/'/>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className="login-page">
            <FormHome {...props}/>
        </div>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    errors: authErrors(state),
    isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onSubmit: (username, password) => {
        dispatch(login(username, password))
    }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Every time I submit the form, I get an error

> Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you
>   misspelled a constant?

I've basically copy and pasted most of the code from that tutorial/repo.  Yet whenever I try to submit the form, it gives me that error.

login action:

```
export const login = (username, password) => ({
    [RSAA]: {
        endpoint: '/api/auth/token/obtain/',
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({username, password}),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        types: [
            LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: looking at your actions/login file, I think you can't return an action without a type key in it.I see types and some other keys in that object, but no type key.May be adding a type key might help here.

Comment: @VivekN that's what I was thinking, but what type key should I add?

Comment: type is some constant string

Comment: @VivekN So where in the example repo do they have that so that they aren't getting the same error?

Comment: ohh I did not notice that you are using redux-api-middleware.Let me see what that package does.At first glance it seems it automatically appends the right type key to the action, so may be you making some mistake while using that npm package.

Comment: can you share the github repo of your codebase

Comment: @VivekN I don't have it on a public repo right now. I'll upload it tomorrow and @ you once I do.

Comment: alright sounds good.

Comment: @VivekN So the issue was actually that I forgot to add the custom middleware.  I skimmed over it and thought it wasn't relevant to the tutorial (because it wasn't mentioned in it).  If you post an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: you can answer it yourself too.For me to answer, I will have to share the corrected code snippet which you have in your repo... :)